# How to disable Enter/Return Key After a function is executed because of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keycode

I have this function where #text_comment is the ID of a textarea:

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress',function (e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        textbox = $(this);
        text_value = $(textbox).val();

        if(text_value.length > 0) {
            $(this).prev().append('<div id="user_commenst">'+text_value+'</div>');
            $(textbox).val("");
        } 
    }                                               
});
```

What is happening is the text is appending when the enter/return key is hit (keyCode 13), but it is also moving the text a line down, as the enter/return key is supposed to.

This is occurring even though I set the value of the textbox to "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here http://jsfiddle.net/Z9KMb/

Comment: @TaylorMac- i think `ugeneK` has given the same answer,40 mins before, then for what you are waiting? working example :D

Comment: lol, I think I know why, might be because he wanted to see the actual implementation before he believes on it. To see is to believe as how they say it. I would give +1 for eugeneK also for everyone who answered right for a credit. It doesn't matter who answered first, what matters most is we tried to help the best we can. :)

Comment: And +1 for TaylorMac for causing this trouble hahaha

Comment: @Ian Jasper Bardoquillo -+1 for your explanantion, why TaylorMac did this.. he he he

Comment: @Vivek: hahaha this is what makes stackoverflow so exciting :) we learn a lot of things

Comment: @Ian Jasper Bardoquillo, it matters to me because i sell StackoverFlow points on ebay.

Comment: @eugeneK :) I'll take your word for it

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 4):

How about [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: How would you preventDefault for specifically the enter key?

Comment: Would bind it to event insde of if statement?

Answer (score 2):

Try and stop your event propagation (See http://snipplr.com/view/19684/stop-event-propagations/) when entering the `if(e.keyCode == 13)` case.

Answer (score 2):

try this one [**event.stopImmediatePropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress',function (e) {       
          if(e.keyCode == 13) {   
               e.stopImmediatePropagation()
       ///rest of your code
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes this works fine. Im sorry, it was another function that was messing it up

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this out, this works. The enter does not create a new line.

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress',function (e) {

    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        textbox = $(this);
        text_value = $(textbox).val();

        if(text_value.length > 0) {
            $(this).prev().append('<div id="user_commenst">'+text_value+'</div>');
            $(textbox).val("");
        }
        return false;
    }                                               
});
```

Although I am wondering, if you don't want to ever have a new line, why are you using a textarea, why not use a input type='text' instead ?