# jQuery Disable Enter Key after Enter Key has been hit when Enter key has already been disabled

Tags: jquery, ajax, double-submit-prevention

I have disabled my enter key so that I can do an ajax submission, but I want to make sure that the form isn't submitted twice if the user hits enter twice before the response from the server comes back.

Here I have disabled the enter key and assigned a function to it called `submitForm()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    offset = $("#quantity").html();
    $("#lastName").focus();
    $(document).bind("keypress" , function(e){
        if (e.which == 13 && (!$("#notes").is(":focus")) && (!$("#submit").is(":focus"))) {
            submitForm(); return false;
        }
    })
    $("#submit").click(function(){ submitForm(); });
});
```

I tried to `bind()` again elsewhere, but it didn't do anything. I tried `preventDefault()` in various places, but I think I'm either putting it in the wrong place, or else that's the wrong thing to do. I can't seem to get this to work.

I found this: [How to disable Enter/Return Key After a function is executed because of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355362/how-to-disable-enter-return-key-after-a-function-is-executed-because-of-it), but it doesn't answer my question because in the poster's example, the script checks to see whether there is anything in the box, but I want to check to see whether I have submitted or not. I'm not sure how to do that. What I would really like to do is disable the enter key until I hear back from the server on the ajax call. Here is submitForm():

```
function submitForm() {
    $.post("/ajax/files" , $("#files").serialize(), function(data){
        filesReset();
        if (data != "") {
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last").prepend(data);
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").find("td").hide();
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").find("td").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:first").effect("highlight" , {"color": "aqua"}, 1000);

            $("#lastInsert table tbody:last tr:last").remove();
        } else {
            alert("Insert rejected: either insufficient criteria or the server is down.");
            $("#hidden").click();
        }
    });
}
```

I would prefer not to have to do anything on the server-side, because I need this submit functionality to be as fast as possible (this will be a fast paced data entry form).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of a variable like this:

```
$(function(){

    var running = false;

    $(document).bind("keypress" , function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
            if(running === false) {
                running = true;
                submitForm();
            }
            return false;
        }
    })

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        if(running === false) {
            running = true;
            submitForm(); 
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier just to change your *submit* button you a *regular* button an use the onclick event to submit the form using JavaScript. That way pressing enter does nothing. Disable the button when it's clicked and enable it on success of your Ajax call.

Comment: That's a good point, and that's what I've done, actually `$("#submit")` is just a button. But `$('#hidden')` is a submit. The reason I left the submit is because for incomplete forms, I use a non-ajax server-side script to mark up the bad controls with messages/suggestions after the alert happens.

Comment: I don't see why you need a submit button at all.